# ASP.NET USERCONTROL WITH UPDATE PANEL INSIDE PAGE UPDATE PANEL

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, triggers, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have a master page with the Scrip manager. Have one page that use the master page and inside of this page i have an updatepanel. Inside this update panel i call a UserControl that have inside other updatepanel.
So i have,

MasterPage ->
   Page with updatepanel ->
      UserControl with update panel

The problem is that the linkbutton event inside the usercontrol updatepanel not fires.
Any help?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPost" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="linkComment" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkComment" runat="server"
             OnClick="linkComment_Click"
             CssClass="PostComment" Text="Comment" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the code of usercontrol.

Thanks

Comment: Does your user control have an ID defined?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `showCommentBox()` is not returning true.

Comment: ok but if i remove the "OnClientClick" the event still not fires. :/